# Blackberry10 cascades

Tags: buttonclick, blackberry-10

I am new to Blackberry 10 development. I have created a button, but I am not able to do the Push screen function from the current screen to next screen. Here is the code I am using:

```
onClicked:{
  navigationPane.push(firstPage);
}
```

And I have also implemented a tab using

```
TabbedPane {
  activePane: Page {
    Label {
      id: label
      text: "What do you like more, kittens or puppies?"

    }
  }
  sidebarState: SidebarState.VisibleCompact
  onActiveTabChanged: {
  }
  Tab {
    title: "Puppies"
    onTriggered: label.text = "kittens"
          NavigationPane {
     id: navigationPane
```

> **`//how to call a screen from this,i got stuck with this,can any some send me simple code for pushing a screen.?`**

```
      }
  }
  Tab {
    title: "Kittens"
    onTriggered: label.text = "I love kittens!"
          NavigationPane {
     id: navigationPane

      >   **`//how to call a screen from this,i got stuck with this,can any some send me simple code for pushing a screen.?`**

      }
  }
}
```

In this tab I want to do a push screen function while clicking the tab's icon. Can anyone help me with these two functions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the example for creating tabs for different screen,you are in main tab to go next qml as follows

```
Tab {
 title: "Puppies"
NavigationPane {
        id: navigationPane
        Sample //this is one qml page as like Sample.qml
       {
        }
    }
```

}

```
Tab {
 title: "Kittens"
NavigationPane {
        id: testpage
        Test //this is one qml page as like Test.qml
       {
        }
    }
```

}

you can access other qml files by setting the id:,

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a NavigationPane inside each Tab, and push inside it:

```
Tab {
title: "Puppies"
onTriggered: label.text = "kittens"
NavigationPane {
   id: navigationPane
}
```

}